# detect the start of Flash videos

Tags: linux, flash, youtube, video-streaming, chromium

I like to turn my music off when I start watching Flash videos. It used to be that Flash videos were cached in `/tmp`, so I could watch for them with inotify:

```
sorghum:~% incrontab -l
/tmp IN_CREATE /home/dmwit/.scripts/flash_movie_start $#
sorghum:~% cat .scripts/flash_movie_start 
#!/bin/sh
case "$1" in
    Flash*)
        mpc pause
        ;;
esac
```

This recently stopped working (at least for YouTube, though some other video sites do still seem to trigger this). After digging around online, I think this may be because YouTube has recently switched over to using RTMP, which doesn't store a cache on disk anywhere.

Is there a way to detect when a browser starts retrieving an RTMP stream?

Comment: Still works here, according to `inotifywait -mqe create /tmp`.

Comment: @grawity Try it with a video that YouTube doesn't own the copyright to, [such as this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBjQ9tuuTJQ). (I assume `inotifywait` is supposed to die when the video starts, right? It doesn't do so here.)

Comment: Die? No, `-m` makes it monitor continuously: `$ inotifywait -mqe create /tmp` → `/tmp/ CREATE FlashXXlanUc5`, when playing that video.

Comment: @grawity It doesn't make any output or do anything at all here. =( flashplugin-10.3.181.34-1, chromium 14.0.835.202-1

Comment: flashplugin 11.0.1.152-1, chromium 15.0.874.106-1, firefox 7.0.1-1, opera 11.52-1... works just fine. You could try looking in `lsof -p <pid>`, where `<pid>` is from `pgrep -lf chromium | grep flash`.